# sql message Table 'testowanie.id' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, insert

I have a problem with my code, I wanted to do that when I click on a checkbox and then on the acceptation button some information will be inserted into my sql database.

There is my code:

```html
<form action="checkboxes.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1"> 4K </input>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>

<?php
/* Database connection */

$sDbHost = 'localhost';
$sDbName = 'testowanie';
$sDbUser = 'root';
$sDbPwd = '';
$Conn = mysql_connect ($sDbHost, $sDbUser, $sDbPwd);
mysql_select_db ($sDbName, $Conn)

$checkbox1 = $_POST['chk1'];
if ($_POST["Submit"]=="Submit") {
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkbox1); $i++) {
$query="INSERT INTO cena (name) VALUES ('".$checkbox1[$i]."')";
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error() );
  }  
echo "Record is inserted";
}
?>
```

But when I click on the button this don't work and a text appears "Table 'testowanie.cena' doesn't exist" but the problem is that the table really exist.

[image]

So if someone can help me it will be great.

Comment: `$_POST['chk1']` isn't an array. You need to use `name="chk1[]"` in the HTML to make it an array.

Comment: And your checkbox doesn't have a valid. `$_POST['chk1']` will just be `on` for all the checked boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the table is `monitory`, `cena` is a column in the table. There is no `name` column. So it should be:

```
$query="INSERT INTO monitory (cena) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($checkbox1[$i])."')";
```

You also need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to prevent SQL-injection. But it would be best if you converted to mysqli or PDO and used prepared queries, since the mysql extension is obsolete and has been removed from the current version of PHP.